# Rounding the height of a table cell in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, adaptive-layout

I need to calculate the cell height of the table and round it to a divisible value by 5. For example, when the cell size is 116, the correct height should be 120.

The point is that I use the adaptive layout to calculate the cell height. One of the subviews of UITableViewCell is a vertical dashed line which should connect to cell below. The dashed line consists of repeating of 5 points - dash (2 points) and gap (3 points). So the height of line view should be rounded up to the value divisible by 5 for correct connection with dashed line of cell which is below.

[image: Two cells with connected dashed line]

Comment: Show your tried code?

Comment: somebody has marked the question as duplicated without understanding the problem - never mind ...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you only want to round up if the value is NOT already a multiple of 5 then something like this is useful:
We need to specifically round down CGFloat (which is what UIViews measure in):

```
let currentHeight = CGFloat(123.456)
let newHeight = ((currentHeight + 4.99) / 5).rounded(.down) * 5
=> 125

let currentHeight = CGFloat(125)
let newHeight = ((currentHeight + 4.99) / 5).rounded(.down) * 5
=> 125
```

I would set the height of the cell to a multiple of five and the height of the dashed-line view to the same.  (I think that is what you intended, just making sure).

Dont forget that you need to set the height of the table cell ***and*** the height of the tableCell.contentView.  Plus you will need to let the UITableView know the height of the cell for its layout.